# What is the character related to this pun?

Tags: translation, names

On [this website](http://great-teacher-onizuka-gto.wikia.com/wiki/Kumiko_Fukada), there is this reference to an intended pun on the name of this character

> The Japanese character for 'KA' in Fukada means shark (which explains her particular teeth).

What would be the character used to do such a pun?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the website should have said

> The Japanese character for 'FUKA' in Fukada means shark

[Apparently her name is 鱶田 久美子](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTO_%28%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB%29) (and 鱶【ふか】 means "(large) shark").